# Floating node of amplifier in LTSpice

Tags: amplifier, analog, ltspice, floating, common-source

I have been trying to create an actively loaded degenerated CS amplifier with current mirror in LTSpice and whilst working on other aspects of the amplifier the Vout node decided it was floating. I'm not sure what changed and i'm not sure of the fix as i would rather not have to redesign the whole amp. Any advice would be great.[image: LTSpice Model]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you get a message about a floating node, it’s a warning issued by the topology checker which is ON by default. The topology checker will automatically add a 1 teraohm resistor to ground on these nodes to prevent issues. My guess is that this warning was always present but the SPICE error log wasn’t auto-popping up after a simulation run. Something else must’ve prompted the error log to pop up, and then that’s when you noticed the floating node warning thinking it’s some kind of new error. I don’t believe there is any issue here but the provided answer can resolve the warning statement.

Answer (score 5):

Add a load resistor from Vout to ground. As it is Vout has no DC path to ground and this will cause the error you’re seeing. You can either use the load impedance you expect the amp to drive or if you don’t want it loaded down use a high value resistance. An easy way to specify a high value in LTspice is to use something like 1E9 for 1 followed by 9 zeros.

Comment: As a side note, SPICE doesn't allow floating nodes. All nodes must have some sort of DC path to ground or power.